# Expose TCP Ports outside the cluster

Tags: openshift

How can be a service that does not use HTTP/s be exposed in Openshift 3.11 or 4.x?

I think routes only support HTTP/s traffic.

I have read about using ExternalIP configuration for services but that makes the operation of the cluster complicated and static compared to routes/ingress.

For example Nginx-ingress-controller allows it with special configurations: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

What are the options in Openshift 3.11 or 4.x?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a section in the official OpenShift documentation for this called [Getting Traffic Into the Cluster](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/index.html).

```
The recommendation, in order or preference, is:
 - If you have HTTP/HTTPS, use a router.
 - If you have a TLS-encrypted protocol other than HTTPS (for example, TLS with the SNI header), use a router.
 - Otherwise, use a Load Balancer, an External IP, or a NodePort.
```

Answer (score 2):

[NodePort](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_nodeport.html) exposes the Service on each Node’s IP at a static port (30000~32767)[0].
You’ll be able to contact the NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting : format.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: "8080"
      protocol: "TCP"
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30000
  selector:
    labelName: targetname
```

Comment: But nodeport is not really a production solution, it opens port in all the nodes, you do not have control about the ports, theoretically the good practice is to let kubernetes gives you the number what makes difficult to manage the deployment of the app between environments and client configurations, is not a smart solution.

Comment: NodePort is a perfectly fine production solution if you are working under constraints that prevent using an ingress/router.