# How to expose the port 9009 in Kubernetes to use InbluxDB Line Protocol

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, questdb

I am currently working on deployment of questdb in Kubernetes, using OpenShift.
I was able to set up questdb very easily using docker image, and I can reach the web GUI with no problem :)

I am also able to get and send data using HTTP REST API, but, since we have huge amount of data to send to the DB, I would like to use the InfluxDB Line Protocol API.
But, since this is using TCP packets, it does not work so far. I was able to send data with that protocol, by giving the IP address specified in the Ingress section, but if I give the URL or hostname, it does not work.
I tried to configure some Routes and Services, but still, it does not work with hostname.

So I was wondering if I have to define a new route, with an additional prefix (such as /exec or /imp). But I was not able to find any information about it.

Being able to send data to questdb, hosted on OpenShift, using the hostname + InfluxDB Line Protocol.

My config so far:

> oc get svc -n ci-questdb
> NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP        EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                                                    AGE
> questdb-temp            ClusterIP      192.168.252.176             8812/TCP,9000/TCP,9009/TCP,9003/TCP                           23h
> questdb-temp-nodeport   NodePort       192.168.146.55              8812:30561/TCP,9000:30242/TCP,9009:31325/TCP,9003:32108/TCP   8m5s
> questdb-test            LoadBalancer   192.168.252.175   10.140.212.94   8812:30112/TCP,9000:30100/TCP,9009:30109/TCP,9003:31256/TCP   10d
> questdb-test-nodeport   NodePort       192.168.238.98              8812:30138/TCP,9000:30875/TCP,9009:32635/TCP,9003:31598/TCP   9m22s

Comment: What ingress controller are you using? and how did you installed using helm or other way? maybe helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57707496/expose-tcp-ports-outside-the-cluster

Comment: I have already checked that page and tried that solution, but it did not help :/
I have tried many config, here is the config I have so far, tried with LoadBalancer and NodePort. 

I'll edit the first post to add my current config, but basically, I am using Loadbalancer and also have a config for NodePort, but that does not work. Looks like it is not able to forward the data from the NodePort to the TargetPort :/

Comment: When you tried to access `NodePort` did you use port `30100` or `9000`? or in general `3xxxx` or `9xxx`

Comment: Actually, since it never worked, I tried both. But even 30100 does not work :/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply forward the port of the pod to local port:

```
kubectl port-forward [pod_name] 9009:9009
```

Or you may create a service, which should look something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: influxdb-service
  labels:
    app: influxdb-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: influxdb-deployment
  ports:
    - port: 9009
      name: influx
      targetPort: 9009
```

Comment: My config actually looks the same as what you are proposing.
Problem is that I do not have permission to use the terminal, then I can only use the GUI to configure my services. 
Maybe there is a problem internally, I'll try to check that with the admins.

Comment: Fundamentally the problem is that ingresses can only handle HTTP/HTTPS/TLS traffic. So for something like a line protocol you will have to define the a LoadBalancer service like this answer specifies. If you only have access to the GUI, that's fine, you should still be able to add the service YAML via the GUI.